# How to get response body using HttpURLConnection, when code other than 2xx is returned?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I have problem with retrieving Json response in case when server returns error. See details below.

#### How I perform the request

I use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. I setup request properties, then I do:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

After that, when request is successful, I get response Json:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
sb = new StringBuilder();
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(output);
}
return sb.toString();
```

#### ... and the problem is:

I can't retrieve Json received when the server returns some error like 50x or 40x,. Following line throws IOException:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
// throws java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: www.example.com
```

The server sends body for sure, I see it in external tool Burp Suite:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

{"type":"AuthApiException","message":"AuthApiException","errors":[{"field":"email","message":"Invalid username and/or password."}]}
```

I can get response message (i.e. "Internal Server Error") and code (i.e. "500") using following methods:

```
conn.getResponseMessage();
conn.getResponseCode();
```

But I can't retrieve request body... maybe there is some method I didn't notice in the library?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Wrong method was used for errors, here is the working code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
if (100 <= conn.getResponseCode() && conn.getResponseCode() <= 399) {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
} else {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
}
```

Comment: `HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream()` (`sun.net.www.protocol.http` implementation) returns `null` unless `responseCode >= 400`, so your check for 299 is probably incorrect.

Comment: If you are using Java 8, you can get the response as a String. `String responseBody = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());`

Comment: The correct range is 200...399, as 3xx is a "redirect" status, not an error.

Comment: @luca.vercelli I think it should be 100..399 because 100..199 is for "Informational" responses as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#1xx_informational_response

Answer (score 159):

If the response code isn't 200 or 2xx, use `getErrorStream()` instead of `getInputStream().`

Comment: in my case, having a response code 403, getErrorStream() returns null

Comment: @Sip 403 is "forbidden". Response payload is possible but not mandatory. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3

Comment: what if the response code is 302 ?

Answer (score 16):

This is an easy way to get a successful response from the server like PHP echo otherwise an error message.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String strCurrentLine;
        while ((strCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
        }
} else {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
    String strCurrentLine;
        while ((strCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
        }
}
```

Comment: the `if(...)` should check more successful codes, in fact all 2xx, not only 200