# java logging the xml response from a server

Tags: java, xml

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 401

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<fulfillmentService><responseCode>1106</responseCode> 
<status>FAILURE</status><systemType>CIS</systemType> 
<responseDescription>Sorry! We are unable to process your request. Call 111 for customer care or visit www.mtnzambia.com.</responseDescription><requestId>WEB_10.100.244.97_92505288-f094-4834-a978-658c19e3f656</requestId></fulfillmentService>
```

I need a way of logging this XML response in java. When I send a request from my java this is what is returned. I need a way of printing out the response description.

Below is my java code:

```
 url = new URL(endpoint);


        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        respTxt = connection.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println("Status code after sending the the payload to mtn => " + responseCode + " Now waiting for response: ");
        Object vm = connection.toString();
        //   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        // send xml to jsp
        // pw.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
        // pw.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the response code isn't 200 or 2xx or 3xx, use getErrorStream() instead of getInputStream().

Please see [How to get response body using HttpURLConnection, when code other than 2xx is returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011927/how-to-get-response-body-using-httpurlconnection-when-code-other-than-2xx-is-re/25012003#25012003)

```
    url = new URL(endpoint);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            respTxt = connection.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println("Status code after sending the the payload to mtn => " + responseCode + " Now waiting for response: ");
            Object vm = connection.toString();
            //   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            //PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            // send xml to jsp
            // pw.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
            // pw.close();
            BufferedReader in;

            if(responseCode >= 200 && responseCode  < 400) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            } else {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
            }
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
```